# When To Use Flowgear Subworkflow

Tags: flowgear

I will creating one demo for used of flowgear subworkflow,i have read help document but i am not understand when to used subworkflow.Can you please give me one example for how to create subworkflow in flowgear and in which situation i used flowgear subworkflow.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of referencing a sub-workflow as the equivalent of calling a function from in function in code. You should factor workflows into multiple workflows and call them from each other when your top level workflow gets too big  (readability), does too many things (separation of concerns) or you need to use elements of a workflow in other places (re-use).